# jQuery recursive search parent element for class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm boggled by what seems like strange behavior from JavaScript/jQuery in a simple function that I wrote to find a parent element by class name. The function is seemingly pretty straightforward in that it checks for a class on an element, if it doesn't find it, it calls the same function with the parent element... until it finds the class.

Here is the relevant JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/xxvywa4v/.

---

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="innermost">Click Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
function getParentByClass($el, className) { 
  if ($el.hasClass(className)) {
    console.log('found element!', $el); // returns correct element
    return $el;
  } else {
    getParentByClass($el.parent(), className);
  }
}

$('.innermost').on('click', function(e) {
  var $outerEl = getParentByClass($(e.target), 'outer');

  console.info($outerEl); // undefined
});
```

**Why is the element correctly logged and found in `getElementByClass`, but is returned to the click handler as `undefined`?**

(Note: I'm not interested in alternative ways to reproduce this functionality, but rather why it isn't working in this particular implementation)

Comment: Doesn't jQuery already have this `.parents()`?

Comment: @Quantastical he says in note that he just wants to know why his implementation does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small error, you are not actually returning what you found in the recursion. You are returning when you find it, but you are not bubbling it up to return that:

```
} else {
    getParentByClass($el.parent(), className);
}
```

You need to put a return there as well: `return getParentByClass($el.parent(), className);`

Comment: Thank you! Completely overlooked returning this result of the recursion.